# CXF: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.ws.rs.MessageProcessingException

Tags: java, jax-rs, cxf

I'm getting some troubles with CXF 2.7.11

I'm trying to extend a jws-based service towards a json-rest implementation.

I have added the following dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

The application starts correctly, but when I access to the wadl url, I have an HTTP 500 Error caused by the following:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.ws.rs.MessageProcessingException
```

Searching in web, I found that the version of javax.ws.rs-api which has that class is the following:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.m01</version>
</dependency>
```

But that version causes another error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/ws/rs/NotFoundException
```

How to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.m10</version>
</dependency>
```